# Is the QCD potential really monotonic ? How does it prevent two quarks from meson to annihilate?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

The QCD potential is made of two terms
-(4/3) * alpha_s / r
that describes the *short* distance

and 
the term 
+k*r
that describes the *long* distance

Of course, alpha is a function of energy, so it is a function of radius.

But in the measurements of QCD potential, I always see that the graphical potential VQCD=f(r) is monotonic, so I would think that it only attracts the two quarks.

So what does prevent the two quarks of the meson to annihilate from the QCD potential. Remark : in the word 'QCD potential', there is Q=quantum, so normally this potential should take into account the quantum effects. Does it take it into account ?

Does the potential stops decreasing at a low radius value ? At which value ? Why the measurements have not been made down to this low r value.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Aren't two quarks in a meson of different types that cannot annihilate? Like an up quark and down antiquark.

Comment: @safesphere Not necessarily. Start with a $\pi^0$ and go on the $J/\psi$ and others.

Comment: take pi0=u ubar for example : from QCD potential, they should annihilate if the monotonic behaviour continues until r=0, but they don't, so somehow something must happen in the low r. But we don't see any change in the monotony of the the plot of VQCD=f(r).

Comment: What, in your vision, happens upon annihilation? What prevents the annihilation "product" from pair producing yet again? What wave functions are you assuming? How does the J/ψ decay?

Comment: the Pi0 is stable. Since the experimental VQCD is monotonic in r, it is attractive. if the u touches the down, they will annihilate. The question is : what allows the meson to be stable while the potential makes the two quarks to attract ?"

Comment: A neutral pion is not stable. Its lifetime is only 84 attoseconds!

Comment: A $u$ and a $d$ do not annihilate. They are not antiparticles. A $u$ annihilates with a $\bar{u}$ and a $d$ with a $\bar{d}$.

Comment: The reason that the $\pi^0$ lives as long as 84 attoseconds is, I believe, the *centrifugal potential*.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that pions are stable?

Answer (score 1):

This monotonic quark-antiquark potential is *phenomenological*, not fundamental. It can be understood as arising from gluon exchange.

The potential *doesn’t* prevent the quark and antiquark in, for example, the neutral pion from annihilating. This annihilation typically produces two photons. A $\pi^0$ decays after a mere 84 attoseconds.

The QCD potential doesn’t stop decreasing as $r$ decreases, any more than the electrostatic potential does. (In both cases, the $1/r$ dependence arises from the exchange of a massless gauge boson. The confining $r$ term in QCD is due to direct gluon-gluon interactions, and has no counterpart in electromagnetism, which does not have direct photon-photon interactions.) However, the strong coupling constant $\alpha_s$ decreases slowly to zero at small distances / large energies. This is called *asymptotic freedom*.

Comment: Thank you. Something is not clear for me. First point : with your reasoning that the "The QCD potential doesn’t stop decreasing as r decreases", this means that *all mesons* will decay. Is it the case ? Second point : since alpha_s (which is in the VQCD formula) tends to 0 as r tends to 0, I deduce that V_QCD should tend to zero when r tends to zero : but this is incompatible with your first sentence, isn't it ? Thank you

Comment: All mesons *do* decay, and do so in small fractions of a second.

Comment: The coupling constant tends to zero at small distances like $1/\log{(1/r)}$. But this doesn’t make the potential go to zero, or change the monotonicity, because the coupling constant is going to zero *more slowly* than the $-1/r$ in the potential is going to negative infinity.

Comment: Thank you. What is limit V_QCD when r tends to 0 : is it -infinite, or is it a finite constant ? If it is a constant, then, how could the quarks approach closer ? If it is -infinite, how could there be asymptotimic freedom. On another approach, asymptotic freedom is established, so how could you explain that the quarks of the mesons annihilate : if there is asymptotic freedom, it means 'no force', so no attraction, so no annihilation. Thank you

Comment: QCD is not my area of expertise, so hopefully someone else will help me out. The potential seems to go to negative infinity. I am not sure how to reconcile this with the idea that asymptotic freedom should mean no force at infinitely short distances. My suspicion is that this phenomenological potential is not valid at short distances. I do not see asymptotic freedom as precluding annihilation because the quark and antiquark have overlapping wavefunctions. Furthermore, even in the absence of the strong force there is still electrostatic attraction between quark and antiquark.

Comment: ok, thank you. Let's see if there is a theorist of QCD that has an idea. The problem is that the "Q"CD potential is supposed to take into account "Quantum" effects. So there is a flaw somewhere in the reasoning. It is not 100 % sure that the VQCD goes to -infinity : we would need to know the expression of alpha_strong expressed as a function of r (instead of energy) and see what happens at small r.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to re-emphasize and elaborate on G. Smith's statement that the potential we're discussing is not a fundamental aspect of QCD.  (Perhaps these remarks should be comments to his answer, but I suspect they'll end up too long and unwieldy for that.)

I believe the main source of confusion here is an assumption that the potential ought to capture all the dynamics of QCD.  I think this is illustrated by the remark, "in the word 'QCD potential', there is Q=quantum", which currently appears in the question.

First of all, I would not use the term "QCD potential" for $V(r) = \sigma r - \frac{A}{r}$.  It's better to think of this as an "effective potential", and I'll mention some reasons for that below.  While you can get some quantum effects out of this potential (most notably a rough spectrum of charmonium [and bottomonium] states predicted by the [Cornell crew](http://inspirehep.net/record/91006) almost 45 years ago), for the full picture you really need to work with the fundamental QCD field theory lagrangian itself.

Now, someone most familiar with **non-relativistic** quantum mechanics might object that the lagrangian is $L = T - V$, so we might expect the potential $V$ provide pretty much the same information as the lagrangian itself.  The key is that [this form for the lagrangian does not hold in relativistic contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), and **relativistic** effects are often crucial in the settings where we consider QCD.  I believe the potential description as a whole is only really appropriate for non-relativistic regimes of the theory (one big reason why it's merely "effective"), though that's not an issue I've thought about deeply.  (I don't do much with non-relativistic QCD in my lattice field theory research.)

The question indicates familiarity with the fact that short distances correspond to high energies, which we can use to qualitatively understand the obstruction to experimental measurements of the potential at arbitrarily short distances $r$.  In order to resolve smaller distances $r$, higher-energy probes have to be used (for example in [deep inelastic scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_inelastic_scattering)), eventually far exceeding the mass-energy of the quarks.  That is, we are now in a relativistic regime whose description in terms of the potential $V(r)$ is questionable at best.

Rather than talking about quark annihilation within mesons (which does occur, as G. Smith pointed out), perhaps it would be useful for me to rephrase this part of the question along the following lines: "Why doesn't the monotonic potential cause the quarks to collapse to $r \to 0$?"  Here is a <strike>sleazy</strike> qualitative way to look at that: If a quark is restricted to a small region $\Delta r$ around $r = 0$, the uncertainty relation $\Delta r \Delta p \gtrsim \hbar$ implies a large quantum uncertainty in its momentum $\Delta p \gtrsim \frac{\hbar}{\Delta r}$ which will very quickly kick it back out to a larger radius.  This is a purely quantum effect that has nothing to do with the QCD coupling or asymptotic freedom.

[As an aside, the QCD coupling does become relevant once that quark is kicked out to a large enough distance---in round numbers, an appropriate 'large' distance would be the charge radius of a typical hadron, approximately a femtometer (fm).  Since $\hbar c \approx 200$MeV$\cdot$fm, this $\Delta r \approx 1$fm implies a typical hadronic energy scale $c\Delta p \sim \frac{\hbar c}{\Delta r}$ of a few hundred MeV, and hence hadron masses far larger than the MeV-scale masses of the up and down quarks.]

While I'm ranting about the potential, let me wrap up by mentioning that there are subtleties at long distances, too.  The major complication here is known as "string breaking" and corresponds to a sufficiently massive/energetic meson decaying into two lighter mesons (for example, the process $\rho \to \pi\pi$).  [This phenomenon is the historical origin of string theory, though the "string" in question is now understood to be an effective description of a "gluonic flux tube".  The coefficient $\sigma$ in the $V(r)$ I wrote above is commonly known as the "string tension".]  In very rough terms, string breaking can be expected once there is enough energy in the system to kick a quark out to a large enough distance $r$ for $\sigma r \subset V$ to be a few hundred MeV---larger than the masses of the two final-state mesons.

Of course, when such few-hundred-MeV energies are at play, we shouldn't expect few-MeV up and down quarks to be non-relativistic.  This is why the "Cornell potential" $V(r)$ I wrote above is most useful for heavier charm and bottom quarks, which are massive enough to make a non-relativistic potential description a reasonable approximation for some purposes.  This is another big reason to consider this potential merely "effective".  In lattice field theory calculations we generally consider the "static potential" defined in the limit where the quarks are infinitely massive (and hence are unable to move with any finite kinetic energy).

Comment: Thank you. Why do you assume that for r close to zero the momentum delta p goes toward the peripherical region and not the central region. Else the reasoning does not work. Also if qcd potential is effective and not a fundamental quantity why do qcd lattice researchers absoletely try to measure it with good precision. If it can t be separated from te lagrangian in relativistic conditions then it makes no sense to measure it ?

Comment: I don't assume the quantum $\Delta p$ fluctuations are oriented in any  special direction.  If you start from a small radius and move a large distance in any direction you end up at a large radius, even if you have to pass through zero to get there.

Comment: The purpose of lattice calculations is to predict non-perturbative emergent phenomena from the underlying strongly coupled field theory.  The long-distance part of the static potential (such as the string tension) is one example of such physics.   Hadron masses and decay constants are other examples.  Even though you can't write the fundamental QCD lagrangian in terms of hadron masses or effective potentials, it's still meaningful to predict these and compare the predictions with experimental measurements.

Comment: Thank you David. So do a meson's quarks annihilate or not ? If yes for which reason ?

Comment: Yes they do, as G. Smith previously explained.

Comment: But you said that delta p uncertainty prevent this..

Comment: To quote my answer above, "quark annihilation within mesons... does occur".  In case you were asking about this due to an incorrect mental picture of the monotonic effective potential causing the quarks to fall in to $r = 0$, I explained how quantum fluctuations prevent hadrons from collapsing to zero size.  The non-zero size of mesons does not prevent the quarks within them from annihilating.  Recall that quarks are ripples in quantum fields that never have an exactly determined position.

Comment: Thank you very much